# read timeout in api calling database causes high open files

Tags: sql, oracle, hibernate, jdbc, hikaricp

I am seeing read timeouts from apis calling database. There are multiple views which are being queried for data. Read timeouts is creating open files on linux running tomcat. Any clues how to debug database views which are causing this issue ?

Comment: You can take a look postgreSQL logs

Comment: @jonathan Johx this is an oracle server

Comment: I was wrong because I assumed it. Then Oracle logs

Comment: This is not enough details to help you.  How long is the timeout value?  What happens if you run the query from sqlplus?  Open file of what?

Comment: Do your views access OS files somehow, like with external tables?